# int256_t using C++ boost library capable of showing 2^{256} - 1

Tags: c++, boost, integer, twos-complement, uint

I'm using the cpp_int header file from boost/multiprecision and for some reason when I cast -1 to a uint256_t then cast it back to an int256_t, it keeps the same value (~1.15e77). When I increment this variable, it wraps back to 0. What gives. Why is my int256_t acting like a uint256_t?

Apologies for bad formatting, I'm not used to using stack overflow.

I tried printing the int256_t and it printed the same value as the uint26_t, which it shouldn't be able to do. I also tried printing int256_t(-1) and it printed -1 fine. If I compare the int256_t to -1 it equates to false, but if I increment them both and then compare it it equates to true as they're both now 0.

Why is this the case? The max uint256_t should be 0xfff....fff, and a signed 2s complement version of -1 in int256_t is 0xfff....fff as well. Is the boost implementation of integers not 2s complement?

Comment: Even though it might not seem necessary, some code demonstrating the issue would be appreciated. I also assume that the library is documented on boost's site. Did you check that out at all?

Comment: I could not reproduce, comparing the int256_t to -1 equated to **true**.  A [mcve] would be very helpful.  I suspect your code has a bug, that I did not reproduce in my code.  Also, thank you for bringing Boost **cpp_int** to my attention, something I was not aware of, and definitely will come in handy for my work.

Comment: A minimal reproducer is mandatory here. For one thing, you completely fail to specify what you mean by "cast". Do you mean static_cast (like all other commenters/answerers)? I have a suspicion you might be reinterpret_casting (perhaps using C-style cast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`int256_t` uses signed magnitude](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) format for number representation, meaning that it separately stores the information about sign and magnitude of the number:

> The type uses a sign-magnitude representation internally, so type int128_t has 128-bits of precision plus an extra sign bit. In this respect the behaviour of these types differs from fundamental (built-in) 2's complement types.

When you cast `int256_t` to `uint256_t`, you strip information about the sign and get the number that is equal to "0 + the signed number". For negatives, this causes a wrap, so for -1 you get `numeric_limits<uint256_t>::max()`. When you cast back, the sign is assumed positive, since by definition unsigned numbers are always positive. The magnitude part of `int256_t` is capable of holding the same number of bits as `uint256_t`, so the conversion is without loss.

Demonstrating:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/effMnhz9a)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
    mp::int256_t si1{-1};
    mp::uint256_t ui1{si1};
    mp::int256_t si2{ui1};

    std::cout << si1 << "\n" << ui1 << "\n" << si2 << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
-1
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
```

Comment: What kind of cast are you imagining when you describe its behaviour? A bit of code would help see whether the behaviour is as-documented or accidental. IME proper conversion with BMP uses `number<>::convert_to<T>`

Comment: @sehe I'm considering code like this: https://godbolt.org/z/djYa56GjP